# Visual Studio cannot open or make project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When I open or create a project in Visual Studio C# 2010 Express I get this error:

> Cannot evaluate the property expression "$([MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('$(VCTargetsPath)','$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\'))" found at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\12.0@VCTargetsPath". Invalid static method invocation syntax: "[MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('$(VCTargetsPath)','$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\')". Method '[MSBuild]]::ValueOrDefault' not found. Static method invocations should be of the form: §([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`, `b`)).

[image: Error message]

I hope someone can solve this problem. I tried re-installing it but it doesn't work. I think it is something with the registry.

Comment: [1] http://i.stack.imgur.com/bG2xC.png

Comment: Thats pretty messed up. I would re-install; but apparently you already tried that... I added the image for you

Comment: Thanks for the image add. Yeah i tried re-installing. But i give it another try :)

Comment: from the looks of the error message, you appear to be attempting to open VS2010 Express, but it is using VS2013 resources (inferred from the ToolsVersion\12.0 path).  Did you at one time have a version of VS2013 installed?

Comment: Looks like your registry is corrupt. Check the registry key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsofot\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\12.0\VCTargetsPath`.  Mine points to `$(MSBuildExtrenstionsPath32\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\`

Comment: yeah i have vs express installed

Comment: Check [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/40a85c8d-483d-4d9b-99e5-bdf63f1b42bb/registry-error-reinstalling-vs-2010-c-express?forum=vssetup) on MSDN.  Also, when you say you have Express installed, please clarify the version VS2010 or VS2013 or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. I removed vs express.
That solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue when I had previously installed VS2013 and then uninstalled. This happens because VS2013 uninstaller forgets one of its registry keys, which causes this error when you start to work with VS2010 again.

Delete if there is a key with 12.0 in this location.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions`

Hopefully VS2010 will work again.

Answer (score 0):

for me the project had created file which exceeded maximum character length path of OS.
problem solved by deleting those file